# LibreOffice 3.5.2.2 in Ubuntu 12.04, request to retrieve documents

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

I'm noticing a few bugs in the Ubuntu 12.04LTS LibreOffice here, he is always opening with a request to retrieve documents on file .odf - Does it have to do with the fact that the openjdk java is installed.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behaviour if Libreoffice is shut down before a document is saved.  Nothing else should affect it.  What did you do on the last occasion you opened and closed Libreoffice is what you need to tell us.